# Moving data from elasticsearch with elasticdump from specific offset

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticdump to move data out of Elasticsearch for further analysis. Now my question is that I am doing it on a running system so I am getting all the time knew data, so how can I start at the last point where I finished like with the offset parameter which is as far as I know no longer allowed in Elasticsearch 6.0.0 or higher?

Commando (has 5 Documents)

```
elasticdump --headers='{"Content-Type": "application/json"}' --offset=2 --input=http://localhost:9200/sessions2-020228 --output=/usr/share/elasticsearch/dump/sessions2-020228.json --type=data
```

error massage which tells me if I get it right that I have a bad request because of the offset argument because without it it works.

```
Mon, 22 Nov 2021 15:19:06 GMT | starting dump
Mon, 22 Nov 2021 15:19:06 GMT | Warning: offsetting 2 rows.
Mon, 22 Nov 2021 15:19:06 GMT |   * Using an offset doesn't guarantee that the offset rows have already been written, please refer to the HELP text.
Mon, 22 Nov 2021 15:19:06 GMT | Error Emitted => {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: using [from] is not allowed in a scroll context;"}],"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: using [from] is not allowed in a scroll context;"},"status":400}
Mon, 22 Nov 2021 15:19:06 GMT | Error Emitted => {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: using [from] is not allowed in a scroll context;"}],"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: using [from] is not allowed in a scroll context;"},"status":400}
Mon, 22 Nov 2021 15:19:06 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Mon, 22 Nov 2021 15:19:06 GMT | dump ended with error (get phase) => BAD_REQUEST: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: using [from] is not allowed in a scroll context;"}],"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: using [from] is not allowed in a scroll context;"},"status":400}
```

Comment: There's no reliable way of doing it, but you can look into the `--offset` parameter of elasticdump to see if that works for your use case.

Comment: Am I using the offset right and do you my by have an idea how I can do what I want to do

Comment: True, sorry my bad, `--offset` is only for version below 6 [#812](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump/issues/812)

Comment: No Problem so do you my by have another idea to get it to work or another tool which I can try.

Comment: How do you define "start at the last point where I finished"? Is your data sorted by timestamp, incremental ID or something?

Comment: Where elasticdump stopped so the last written offset. (for example get the line size of the last written document)